# Array Loop - Dealing with null values in dropdown

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-maps, loops, jquery-selectors

I need help with this loop through an array. Right now I have 3 dropdown menus. I am trying to loop through my array and say if a value from a drop down menu matches a value in the array then run a function (that plots markers on my map). It all works.

EXCEPT, All 3 dropdown menus have to match a value currently, How can I say if one value matches and the rest are null plot all those locations? Does that make sense? I need to account for 1 or 2 or even 3 drop down menus not being selected. Let me know if you need to see more code.

```
for (var i = 0; i <mymarkers.length; i++) {
    if (mymarkers[i].type==type&&mymarkers[i].day==day&&mymarkers[i].time==time){
        mymarkers[i].setMap(MYMAP.map);
    }else{
        mymarkers[i].setMap(null);
    }
}
```

This might not be specifically a map problem, but it is a problem that is related to my finishing a location map. Here is a link: http://mycwebdesign.com/meetings.php. If you select "MA" and "Friday" and "Late" you will see it work.

Comment: This isn't a maps problem, surely? It's a `<select>` problem. A demonstrator example would be good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want for any marker with properties is for its properties to match the selected property (`true` will put it on the map) OR for the selected property to be `--`, so that test is also `true`.

```
if ((mymarkers[i].type==type || type=='--') &&
    (mymarkers[i].day==day   || day =='--') &&
    (mymarkers[i].time==time || time=='--')) {
```

If `type=='--'` then it doesn't matter what `mymarkers[i].type` is: that test will be `true`.

You will probably need the three lines of code above to be all on one line. It's easier to see what's going on here with it split up.

Comment: YAY!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Thank you sir. The final piece of the puzzle is now in place. Thank you very much.